# moving the dom position of element in each loop of selector in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, each

So I have this DOM structure for a news feed

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="date">01 July 2015</h2>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="somesource">
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <a href="#link">link</a>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A id vero rerum consectetur itaque ex saepe quia nam quam est!
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

//duplicated 5 times
```

I want to move the link before the `h2.date` and my jQuery code goes like this:

```
$('.content .row .description').each(function() {
    var hrefs = $('a', this);
    hrefs.insertBefore('.content .row h2.date');
});
```

Instead of getting it's link only, it keeps dumping all of the links from the other news also:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <a href="#link">link</a>
        <a href="#link2">link from news 2</a>
        <a href="#link3">link from news 3</a>
        <a href="#link4">link from news 4</a>
        <a href="#link5">link from news 5</a>
        <h2 class="date">01 July 2015</h2>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="somesource">
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A id vero rerum consectetur itaque ex saepe quia nam quam est!
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.insertBefore()` selector has no context, so your elements are inserted into the first element matching your selector:

```
$('.content .row .description').each(function() {
    var hrefs = $('a', this),
        $target = $(this).closest('.content').find('.row h2.date');
    hrefs.insertBefore($target);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgvcesg6/)

Or, avoid having to traverse *up* the DOM tree, by looping `.content` instead:

```
$('.content').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $href = $this.find('a'),
        $target = $this.find('.row h2.date');
    $href.insertBefore($target);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgvcesg6/2/)

Comment: was just starting an answer to suggest looping over outer elements also. Makes the most sense to me also

Comment: hmmm, still not working.It still returning the bunch of links before the `h2` from the other news.  Anyway here's the actual link of the site, you  might wanna see what's happening:

http://fas.srmconsultancy.org

The section below the "view all news" button. These are fetched content from an external site so i need to re-arranged the markup for me to be able to style it easily.

Comment: @George , alright here you go:

for the 1st one: http://jsfiddle.net/0gpfgdb4/
for the 2nd one: http://jsfiddle.net/rd9keLn4/

Comment: @George , thanks for your help i think i got it to work. There's no problem with the solution you've given. My problem is with the scoping of my selector. The `.description` class is causing the trouble so i need to remove it. Thanks for the help of jQuery facebook group too (Kim).